# Sanitize helper causing an error in Money gem in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, currency, sanitize

Calling "sanitize" method on anything causes a missing method error in Rails 3 with Collective Idea's [Money](https://github.com/collectiveidea/money) Gem

```
sanitize "trololo"
```

=>

```
undefined method `id2name' for {:instance_writer=>false}:Hash

collectiveidea-money (1.7.4) lib/support/cattr_accessor.rb:7:in `block in cattr_reader'
collectiveidea-money (1.7.4) lib/support/cattr_accessor.rb:5:in `each'
collectiveidea-money (1.7.4) lib/support/cattr_accessor.rb:5:in `cattr_reader'
collectiveidea-money (1.7.4) lib/support/cattr_accessor.rb:54:in `cattr_accessor'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/vendor/html-scanner/html/sanitizer.rb:48:in `<class:LinkSanitizer>'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/vendor/html-scanner/html/sanitizer.rb:47:in `<module:HTML>'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/vendor/html-scanner/html/sanitizer.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:174:in `white_list_sanitizer'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:60:in `sanitize'
```

Has anyone experienced this error before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging around in the source code I found this: The *money* gem defines the `cattr_accessor` helper methods (see in file YOUR_GEM_DIR/collectiveidea-money-1.7.4/lib/support/cattr_accessor.rb) as does active_support (see in file YOUR_GEM_DIR/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute_accessors.rb).

Unfortunately, the implementation in the *money* gem differs from the one in active_support. And in your case, the *money* gem has been loaded after active_support and overwrote the *good* active_support implementation.

You can "fix" it by making sure that the *money* gem is loaded before active_support. If you post more details about your application, I can tell you how to do that...

However, the *money* gem seems to be pretty outdated, so I suggest you replace it with something that is more recent and actively maintained...

Comment: Do you have any idea which gem(s) could possibly replace 'money' gem?
I have no clue after googling and browsing the ruby-toolbox.com

Comment: This fork here: https://github.com/zacheryph/money has the `cattr_accessor` problem solved...